# 2011 Mac Mini boot camp problems

Tags: bootcamp, windows, driver

I Have a 2011 Mac mini and I installed Windows 7 using Bootcamp. All the drivers are working fine, except the sound and the bluetooth. Since my internet connection is really lousy, I don't want to download a 100Mb drivers solution, I just need the Audio Controller, which I've been led to believe that it a Cirrus Logic CS4206B, but I haven't been able to find a single place to download the driver.

Can anyone point out any advice on how I can solve this? By providing a link to download the driver, or perhaps a way to extract it from somewhere, because bootcamp requires me to connect to internet to download the whole driver pack and I just can't do that.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**: Just for the sake of information, my Mac is a mid 2011 Mac Mini, having a 2.3Ghz Core i5 and an 8Gb RAM kit installed by me.

**UPDATE** After a while, I managed to install the Cirrus Logic driver, so I-m marking the answer as correct, however, I get audio only in the internal speaker, no audio on the Jack. I'll try to reinstall using Bootcamp 3.2 and see what happens.

**UPDATE** It's been a while since I posted this question, but I'll say my current solution. After many different ideas and trying with almost every variation of the Cirrus driver, I was able to use the download Windows support drivers and everything worked like a charm, so in the end, it was the only option to get a proper bootcamp installation.

Comment: Where exactly is the "new driver entry" option? Can't find it anywhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1: Download the most recent Cirrus Logic drivers from the Cirrus Logic page. The CS4207 driver is actually more appropriately named "CS42**" driver.

--> go to this page: [Here](http://www.cirrus.com/en/products/cs4207.html)

--> click the "Resources" tab

--> in the "Resources" tab, under the "Tools & Software" heading, select the appropriate driver ZIP file for your particular configuration. Since I am operating in Windows 7 64 bit, I chose the "CS4207 Windows Vista (32/64-bit) and Windows 7 (32/64-bit) Driver, 8/2010, v6.6001.1.26 : 100 KB"

--> download the file to your desktop

--> create a folder on your desktop called CS4207 Drivers (the name doesn't actually matter)

--> move the downloaded ZIP file to this new folder

--> expand the ZIP file within this new folder

Step 2. Go to Control Panel, Device Manager.

Step 3. In Device Manager, open up the "Sound, vide and game controllers" sub menu.

Step 4. If you're like me, you had 4 NVIDIA High Definition Audio entries, and one Cirrus or Intel entry. Click on the Cirrus or Intel entry for the Sound controller. Uninstall the driver and, if it gives you the option to delete the driver files used, do so.

Step 5: Go back to Device Manager, and select "Scan for hardware changes" from the right click dropdown menu.

Step 6. Let your system automatically install whatever driver it wants.

Step 7. Select that new driver entry in Device Manager; right click the entry to update the driver; choose the Browse option, then the Let Me Pick option; and then select the new folder on your desktop as the driver location.

Comment: hey Split71! Thanks for the info, I already had the driver and tested those exact (kinda) steps, no joy with that...

Comment: Now, I-ve installed both of the drivers (The Intel and the Cirrus one), both show as OK, but still no sound. yes, the speakers are on :)

Comment: Marked you answer as correct, because after all, the driver did worked. And I have no other response.. :)