# Windows7 (through bootcamp) poor sound quality problem

Tags: audio, macbook-pro, windows, driver

I installed windows7 through bootcamp on my macbook air(2011).
(and also installed windows driver from bootcamp)
Everything is OK, but one problem - Sound quality is very poor.
(maybe phone or radio quality?). In OSX, quality is good.
I tried to change audio setting, sound quality tab, etc.,
but not fixed. 
Audio driver info shows "Cirrus Logic CS4206B (AB 91)".
I googled for the updated driver, and found this :
[2011 Mac Mini boot camp problems](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/35402/2011-mac-mini-boot-camp-problems)
I tried it, but problem has not been fixed.
Any idea? would be welcomed.

Comment: Just to be clear, it seems like you're saying you tried installing the Intel, Cirrus, and windows drivers, correct, or no? Also, while it's not clearly stated, I assume that the sound is fine when you boot to OSX, right?

Comment: blunders > At the first time I installed only windows7 drivers given by bootcamp. And I found that sound is poor. The sound is fine when I boot to OSX. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Did you attempt running the updates for Windows and looking at the optional updates?

Comment: Yes, I did extra windows update to ServicePack1, etc..

Comment: No, I'm not talking about the suggested updates (aka Service-Packs, Security-Updates, etc) -- I'm talking about the optional updates. Sound updates are always optional. Are you saying you did just the suggested updates, or did them and checked the optional updates for any sound related updates?  From Microsoft: "[Optional updates are not downloaded or installed automatically.](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Install-Windows-updates)" -- though I'm unable to find how to do this, if you are not either, I'd suggest posting it as a question on [SuperUser.SE](http://superuser.com).